# Simple Harmonic Motion ( Spring block system )

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

If a block of mass m is attached to one free end of a spring and is performing simple harmonic motion of some amplitude A . Now if a wall is placed at some distance x (x < A ) from its mean position . It collides elastically, how is its amplitude going to change ? [ Will it be different in the side with the wall or uniform throughout? ]

Comment: If no energy is lost in the collision, you would expect the mass to "instantaneously" change the sign of its velocity. Hence, it would look as though the mass had completed its oscillatory behavior and reached the point at which it hit the wall. From that point on, the movement would be indistinguishable from the case without wall until it comes back and hits the wall again, to repeat the same process all over.

Comment: does it basically mean that , after the purely elastic collision , the velocity is again the same which it would been without the wall so the rest part of the collision takes place undisturbed